# Flutter : How to Integrate Recurring(subscription) Payment in Stripe

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Is there a way to create a monthly subscription via flutter and stripe? I want to integrate stripe payment gateway with flutter, I saw a lot of plugins available in pub.dev, but  I could not find subscription types of payment(Recurring Based). can anyone suggest to me a plugin or idea to do this in flutter?

Comment: For this to work efficiently you need a backend. What is your backend ?

Comment: codeigniter framework(php5.6)

Comment: So you must implement stripe payment in your backend and call your own api from your api. This is for your own safe. Putting strip ApiKey in your flutter app is hugely unsafe

Comment: i appreciate it, am already tried in back end but its not fulfilled, atleast i need to create  customer  from flutter plugin(becoz subscription need customer with card details with frontend validation) so that i can make subscription using created customer id from backend.

Comment: You customers info must be recorded in your backend (but not their card number) for their privacy protection. Then each time you want to interact with stripe, the frontend part is in the customer interfaces and the backend do the rest of the job

Comment: The Theme is monthly payment(automatic) so that i cannot ask card details for every month to the customer.

Comment: The save it but make sure they remain safe